# why model's maximum context length is 4096 tokens of gpt-3.5-turbo-0125?

Tags: azure, azure-openai

i am calling the azure openai using `gpt-3.5-turbo-0125` as listed in https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5-turbo

```
openai.api_key = "*****"
openai.api_base = "https://lge-chatgpt-002.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_type = 'azure'
openai.api_version = '2023-09-01-preview'
MODEL = 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0125'

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(  # type: ignore
                        engine = "gpt-35-turbo",
                        model = MODEL,
                        messages = messages,
                        temperature=0,
                        max_tokens=max_tokens,
                        stop= None
                    )
```

however, i got error:

> This model's maximum context length is 4096 tokens. However, you
> requested 4274 tokens (3774 in the messages, 500 in the completion).
> Please reduce the length of the messages or completion.

from the website, the max context length is 16,385 tokens. so any reason for this error ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

16k is the context size limit, including both input + output tokens.

4k is the limit of the output tokens. Make sure you set max_tokens <= 4096 and input_tokens + max_tokens <= 16385 when you call the API.